# How to I wrap text in a Tooltip with javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, tooltip

I have an `ArrayList` that I am trying to get into a `Tooltip` when the mouse hovers over a `Node`.  I have everything set, but I can't figure out how to wrap text in the `Tooltip` in order to display each item in the `ArrayList` on a separate line in the `Tooltip`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define 2 different properties, a `prefWidth` for your tooltip and set [`wrapTextProperty` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html#wrapTextProperty) to `true`.

Your code will somewhat look like this

```
Tooltip t = TooltipBuilder.create().text(str).prefWidth(100).wrapText(true).build();
```

Comment: I think the builder pattern is obsolete in JavaFX 8

Comment: Yes. This solution will work with JavaFX 2. This answer will be deleted if OP specifies which version he's using.

Comment: I am not using JavaFX 8, so this does fix my problem!

Comment: Well it will work at least until somebody tries to run the app on Java 9 dgelinas.  In Java 9 the deprecated builder methods will be dropped from the JRE, so a program using them will never work with Java 9+.  You can easily get around that issue by simply not using the Builders (which is advisable).  Also using JavaFX versions prior to Java 8 is not advised as they are obsolete an unsupported.

Answer (score 7):

Solution which does not rely on the deprecated TooltipBuilder:

```
Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip(str);
tooltip.setPrefWidth(100);
tooltip.setWrapText(true);
```